# Efficient cartesian product algorithm ignoring terms

Tags: performance, algorithm, clojure, cartesian-product

Let's say I have sets `A_1,...A_n,` e.g. `[[a b c][d e][f]]`.  I would like to find Cartesian product of these sets but not including any terms which are supersets of elements of some ignore list.

For instance if my ignore list is `[[a e][c]]`, the result of the Cartesian product would be `[[a d f][b d f][b e f]]`.  Note any term with `c` is not in there, neither is `[a e f]`.

Of course one way I  could do this is to find the full cartesian product and then remove the offending items, but I would like a more efficient way, such that I avoid checking solutions in the first place.

I have an initial solution which involves incrementally building each term in the cart-product, and at each stage I remove any elements from `A_i` if adding them to the term I am building would cause it to be a superset of any one of the ignores.
This works fine, and is better than the naive solution, but there is still a large amount of redundant checking, which also depeneds on the order in which the sets are presented.  E.g. if `[f]` was in my ignore list, I would still keep trying to create terms until I reach `[f]` and then discard.

For concreteness, my clojure implementation is

```
(defn first-elements
  "Get the first elements of a set of sets, unless ignored"
  [sets ignores in-ignore?]
  (loop [product-tuple [] sets sets]
    (println "sets " sets)
    (cond
      (or (nil? sets) (nil? (first sets)))
      product-tuple

      :else
      (if-let [set-op (remove #(in-ignore? product-tuple ignores %) (first sets))]
        (if (and (coll? set-op) (empty? set-op))
            product-tuple
            (recur (conj product-tuple (first set-op)) (next sets)))
        product-tuple))))

(defn in-ignore?
  "if I add elem to this build will it become a superset of any of the ignores"
  [build ignores elem]
  (some  #(clojure.set/superset? (conj (set build) elem) %) ignores))

(defn cartesian-product-ignore
  "All the ways to take one item from each sequence, except for ignore"
  [ignores original-sets]
  (loop [cart-prod #{} sets original-sets]
    (let [firsts (first-elements sets ignores in-ignore?)]
      (print "firsts " firsts "-cart-prod " cart-prod " sets " sets "\n")
      (cond
        (zero? (count firsts))
        cart-prod

        (= (count sets) (count firsts))
        (recur (conj cart-prod firsts) (update-in sets [(dec (count sets))] next))

        :else
        (recur cart-prod (assoc
                           (update-in sets [(dec (count firsts))] next)
                           (count firsts)
                           (original-sets (count firsts))))))))
```

Answer (score 7):

I think there are some improvements that can be made over your current approach.  But first, let's implement a basic `cartisian-product`.  Then we can adapt it to accept an ignores list.  This is easy enough using `for` and some recursion:

```
(defn cartesian-product [colls]
  (if (empty? colls)
    (list ())
    (for [e (first colls)
          sub-product (cartesian-product (rest colls))]
      (cons e sub-product))))

;; Quick test run
(cartesian-product [[:a :b :c] [:d :e] [:f]])
=> ((:a :d :f) (:a :e :f) (:b :d :f) (:b :e :f) (:c :d :f) (:c :e :f))
```

Good.  And since we're using `for`, we have the advantage of laziness.  If you need your result to be something other than a sequence of sequences, it's easy enough to convert it to something else.

Now, the hard part -- implementing the ignore sets.  According to your description, your current approach is to remove elements from A_i if adding them to the term you are building would cause that term to become a superset of any of the ignore sets.  As your code illustrates, not only is this somewhat inefficient (for example, `superset?` is worst-case linear time w.r.t. the size of its first parameter), but it also makes the code more complicated than it needs to be.

So let's adopt a different approach.  Instead of removing elements from A_i, let's remove any elements we add to a term from the ignore sets.  Then we can prune a term if any of the ignore sets are empty.  As a bonus, all it requires is a few changes to our previous `cartesian-product` implementation:

```
(defn cartesian-product-ignore [ignore-sets colls]
  (cond (some empty? ignore-sets) () ; prune
        (empty? colls) (list ())     ; base case
        :else                        ; recursive case
        (for [e (first colls)
              sub-product (cartesian-product-ignore (map (fn [s]
                                                           (disj s e))
                                                         ignore-sets)
                                                    (rest colls))]
          (cons e sub-product))))

;; test without any ignore sets
(cartesian-product-ignore [] [[:a :b :c] [:d :e] [:f]])
=> ((:a :d :f) (:a :e :f) (:b :d :f) (:b :e :f) (:c :d :f) (:c :e :f))

;; Now the moment of truth
(cartesian-product-ignore [(set [:a :e]) (set [:c])] [[:a :b :c] [:d :e] [:f]])
=> ((:a :d :f) (:b :d :f) (:b :e :f))
```

Of course, minor changes may be required to fit your exact needs.  For example, you might want to accept ignore sets as a vector or sequence and convert them to sets internally.  But that is the essence of the algorithm..

Comment: This algorithm is totally awesome!

Comment: This doesn't seem to address OP's concerns. Namely, the amount of work is in the worst case proportional to the size of the un-pruned cartesian product, which could be many times more than the size of the final answer.

Comment: @n.m, I think the work done by the final algorithm presented here should be proportional to the size of the final answer.  Why do you think it isn't?

Answer (score 2):

Here a core.logic (naive) approach

```
(ns testing
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [==])
  (:use [clojure.core.logic])
)
(run* [q]
       (fresh [x y z]
              (membero x [:a :b :c])
              (membero y [:d :e])
              (membero z [:f])
              (== q [x y z])
              (!= q [:a :e z] )
              (!= q [:c y z] )

              )
       )

==> ([:a :d :f] [:b :d :f] [:b :e :f])
```

Although it's much more slow than @Nathan_Davis algorithm, 23.263 msecs vs 0.109 msecs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics)

Comment: I don't see any function in `clojure.math.combinatorics` that allows some terms to be skipped.

Comment: yeh sorry I didn't read the question properly - it's a feature that would be nice to have in math.combinatorics

Comment: No problem.  And hey, being open source, maybe you can add it -- then it'd be a correct answer ;-)